# Permissions to create AKS cluster with Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

Looking into using AKS but having some issues/queries when creating.

I can create a cluster using the following CLI command:

`az aks create --resource-group myRG --name aks --node-count 2 --generate-ssh-keys --enable-managed-identity --attach-acr myACR`

And this creates it fine without any issues. I want to add Application Gateway which is causing me issues and have narrowed it down to the following call:

`az aks create --resource-group myRG --name aks --node-count 2 --generate-ssh-keys --enable-managed-identity --attach-acr myACR --network-plugin azure`

By setting the `--network-plugin` to Azure it fails with the following error:

```
ValidationError: Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. For how to configure, please refer 'https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal'. Original error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Setting the `--debug` flag on the call displays the following:

```
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): graph.windows.net:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://graph.windows.net:443 "POST /1f141cfd-a6c5-4e9a-bf84-7116c141e5f4/applications?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1" 403 219
msrest.http_logger : Response status: 403
...
msrest.http_logger : {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"65e9cb16-4df1-4824-bd33-3ee6f691ed07","date":"2020-10-19T10:58:49"}}
```

So I can see that it's because I do not have permissions to create an app in Azure AD.

I do not have access to Azure AD as it's a corporate one, but wondering the following:

1. What are the lowest permissions required for me to be able to create AKS in AD?
2. Can the Azure AD owner create me an application for me to then use? How would I reference this when creating the cluster?
3. Is Managed Identities preferred over Service Principals? Can managed identities be used with existing AD objects?

I have a feeling some of my questions show my lack of understanding/knowledge of how permissions work with Azure AKS/AD, but am having trouble understanding as there is not a lot readable errors (I can't even access Azure AD pane within the portal).

Comment: Can you share more logs (the context of the 403 error)? I tested this cmd but in my log I cannot find the operation of registration of Azure AD app.

Comment: Do you still need help on this issue?

Comment: @AllenWu Not sure to be honest. As I said, if I run the above command it returns the permissions issue when trying to create an application in Azure AD. However, if I supply dummy service principle info in the same command e.g. `--service-principal 1234 --client-secret 1234` it then creates it fine. I've had a play around with it and seems to be working ok even though the service principal doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you share the full cmd which includes `--service-principal 1234 --client-secret 1234`?

Comment: @AllenWu `az aks create --resource-group rg --name aks --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys --enable-managed-identity --attach-acr myacr --network-plugin azure -a ingress-appgw --appgw-name myApplicationGateway --appgw-subnet-prefix "10.2.0.0/16" --service-principal 1234 --client-secret 1234`. So without the `service-principal` it says I don't have the permissions to create an application in AD, but works with a non-existent service principal supplied